# Dragon Bones / Starling wrong syncing of timeline animations containing easing

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, starling-framework, jsfl

maybe you guys here can help me (because I already tried the starling/dragonbones forums and nobody answered...).

I'm having a problem with syncing timeline animations that contain ease that not start at the same frame.

Let me show the problem.

I have the following timeline:
[image]

The two layers containing animations that start at frame 0 are starting with Tween Ease out = 100 (as you can see in the image below) and finishing with easing 0.

[image]

Now if I try to visualize it in the DragonBones Flash Panel the animation sync between easing animations will not sync as seen below:

[image]

In first place I didn't know if DB even was supporting it, but than I saw in the skeleton.xml (the exported file can be found here https://db.tt/QruadM3t) the easing values as displayer below:

```
...
<timeline name="black1" scale="1" offset="0">
        <frame z="0" tweenEasing="1" duration="48">
          <transform x="753.3" y="207.45" skX="0" skY="0" scX="1" scY="1" pX="0" pY="0"/>
        </frame>
        <frame z="0" tweenEasing="0" duration="1">
          <transform x="124.35" y="207.45" skX="0" skY="0" scX="1" scY="1" pX="0" pY="0"/>
        </frame>
        <frame z="0" duration="1">
          <transform x="124.1" y="207.45" skX="0" skY="0" scX="1" scY="1" pX="0" pY="0"/>
        </frame>
      </timeline>
...
```

And now I don't know if it's a real bug or if I'm doing something wrong.

Can somebody help me with this one?

Ow, if somebody wants so see by himself the fla's can be downloaded via https://db.tt/xKFQ5IBT for the CS5 version or via https://db.tt/mKdvkPn9 for the CS6 version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't really answer the question either, but eventhough the guys have made a great job, it is not to be trusted on a commercial level. It has lots of bugs, not good documentation and they almost never reply in time (like most open source projects :/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let everybody know,

it was a bug in BD and I patched it... the pull request (https://github.com/DragonBones/DragonBonesAS/pull/40) was already merged, so if you're running the latest version of BD you have the fix :)

Cheers.